# Number of rows increases and data corrupts in resulting csv

Tags: scala, csv, dataframe, apache-spark, parquet

Converting dataframe from one form to another:

```
Parquet -> Parquet (number of rows remains same, NO PROBLEM)
Parquet -> CSV     (number of rows INCREASES! Data corruption!)
```

First read data from parquet, then convert to csv/parquet using below command :

```
<input_dataframe>.coalesce(1).write.option("header", true).csv/parquet(output_path)

scala> spark.read.option("header", true).parquet(input_path).count
Long = 8387913

scala> spark.read.option("header", true).csv(output_path).count
Long = 8387932
```

As a result of this rows are getting mixed with one another, and the records are getting spilled over or corrupted.

There is a workaround to it ONLY in case you have to read the csv **using spark**. You can pass option `multiline` as `true`.

```
scala> spark.read.option("header", true).option("multiline", true).csv(output_path).count
Long = 8387913     <<  input parquet contains same number of records
```

But this is not what I want to do with the CSV. I need to read it without using spark.

How do I keep the structure intact while **writing dataframe to csv**?

NOTE: This might not be a reproducible case with all dataframes. My data has it for some unknown reasons. I noticed this problem when I found string type field are storing integral value in resulting CSV, and a whole set of records being corrupt with arbitrary values. CSV size ~ 2.5 GB.

Comment: That is because ```\n``` will be considered as new record in csv file format.

Comment: Try escaping commas and replace \n

Comment: First of all. Parquet knows nothing about `header` option. Then, the method to created/write data, is it the one shown in the code snippet?